# how to send value with ajax jquery to contorller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

how to send id to controller without the input type hidden and send them with forms and submit the value to delete the product id how to do it?

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ReOrder", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <input type="hidden" id="lblID" name="id"  />
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>ProductID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Operations</th>
                </tr>


                @foreach (MyProduct product in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.ProductID</td>
                        <td>@product.Name</td>
                        <td>@product.Color</td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="Delete(@product.ProductID)" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }


  function Delete(id) {          
      $('#lblID').val(id);         
      document.forms.item(id).submit();
  }
```

Comment: You want to call the controller via ajax ? did you try jquery $.post /$.ajax  ?

Comment: Remove the outer form and the script, and inside the loop - `<td>@Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ReOrder", new { id = product.ProductID })) { <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> }<td>` But a delete action must be a POST, not a GET. But you would be better off using ajax, and in its success callback, remove the row if sucessful, so the user can stay on the same page and continue to delete items.